# C# Json Key change with String

Tags: c#, json, string

What I am trying to do is make a program in C# (Visual Studio 2017) where you'd input a string. And you have a Json string that's deserialized in to an object. I have the libraries Newtonsoft Json library to handle my Json strings and files. But I want to be able to change it with a string. For example

```
internal static void ChangeSettings(String Dir, string s, string[] value)
{
    String SettingsString = File.ReadAllText(Dir);

    DefaultSettings Settings = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DefaultSettings>(SettingsString);

}
```

And this is my class file for `DefaultSettings`

```
internal class DefaultSettings
{
    public string ReportLogChannel { get; set; }
    public string RespondReport { get; set; }
    public string AutoPrefixRulesOrTutorials { get; set; }
}
```

Now let's say that the json is `{"ReportLogChannel":"None","RespondReport":"","AutoPrefixRulesOrTutorials":"true"}`

And I input a string. For example `"ReportLogChannel"` then I want to select that key. And then later change it to another string. So. This is for a Discord bot. Now. So. In the the Json. We have the key `"ReportLogChannel"`. If I input a string. `"ReportLogChannel"`. Then it will select that object with the `Settings` and the field value

Comment: What's the question exactly? :)

Comment: If I have a class with the properties
    public class DefaultSettings
    {
        public string ReportLogChannel { get; set; }
        public string RespondReport { get; set; }
        public string AutoPrefixRulesOrTutorials { get; set; }
    }
and I want to get and set the value. If I have the string `"RespondReport" and want to get a value and set a value with the string. And get the object. Instead of doing
    DefaultClass Settings=new DefaultClass();
    if(OptionObject="RespondReport") {}
So instead of doing a bunch of `if(...=...){Console.WriteLine(Settings.RespondReport)}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it! Finally. This is what I came up with

```
DefaultSettings Settings = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DefaultSettings>(SettingsString);
Console.WriteLine(Settings.GetType().GetProperty(s).GetValue(Settings, null).ToString());
Settings.GetType().GetProperty(s).SetValue(Settings, value);
```

Where `s` is the property I wanted to get. And value is a string with all strings part that I want to put in the value.